# Prove a metric space is complete

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

The real line $\Bbb R$ endowed with the metric $d(x,y):=\min(1,|x-y|)$ is complete.

Do I have to prove that every Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ converges or is there an easier way?

Comment: well have you tried to use the definition? there exists alway $K$ such that $|x_m-x_n|<1$ for every $m,n\geq K$.

Comment: The easiest way is to show that every Cauchy sequence in that metric is also Cauchy in the usual metric, and use the fact that $\Bbb R$ with the usual metric is complete.

Answer (score 1):

If $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, then there exists $K\in\Bbb N$ such that $|x_n-x_m|<1$. Then it follows from the completeness of $\Bbb R$ with the usual absolute value.